# Pythonic way to find what's wrong with a json file

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am working on a script that convert a `json` data to a `panadas.DataFrame`/`numpy.array`.

When the json is ok there is no problem but when there is something wrong I got a general error telling me that this is not a correct json format.

I am looking for a Pythonic to know exactly what's wrong with the json. Something that can point to the error in the json file.

For example:

With ths json, everything is OK,

```py
    [
      {
      "col1": value1,
      "col2": value2,
      "col3": value3,
      "col4": value4,
      "col5": value5,
      "wpId": xxxxxx
      },
      { 
      "col1": value1,
      "col2": value2,
      "col3": value3,
      "col4": value4,
      "col5": value5,
      "wpId": xxxxxx
      },
      {
      "col1": value1,
      "col2": value2,
      "col3": value3,
      "col4": value4,
      "col5": value5,
      "wpId": xxxxxx
      }
    ]
```

But with this:

```py
    [
      {
      "col1": value1,
      "col2": value2,
      "col3": value3,
      "col4": value4,
      "col5": value5,
      "wpId": xxxxxx
      },
      { 
      "col1": value1,
      "col2": value2,
      "col3": value3,
      "col4": value4,
      "col5": value5,
      "wpId": xxxxxx
      }, []
      {
      "col1": value1,
      "col2": value2,
      "col3": value3,
      "col4": value4,
      "col5": value5,
      "wpId": xxxxxx
      }
    ]
```

I would that the script return something like:

```
  ERROR: "},[]{" is not a json format.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it by myself:

```py
import json

try:
  data = json.loads(open("error_data.json").read())
except ValueError as err:
  print(err)

>> Expecting , delimiter: line 28 column 5 (char 772)
```